# Why is sendmail not found?

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, vps

I've just installed Postfix on Debian and am following [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu) on my VPS.

When I execute the command:
`$ echo "test email" | sendmail your-account@gmail.com`

`sendmail: command not found`

Why is this happening?

Someone suggested I run the following:

```
$ sudo find / -name "sendmail"
/var/lib/sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail
/usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
/usr/lib/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/logcheck/ignore.d.server/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/network/if-down.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/network/if-post-down.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/network/if-up.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/ppp/ip-down.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/ppp/ip-up.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/examples/resolvconf/update-libc.d/sendmail
/usr/share/sendmail/sendmail
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/sendmail
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/sendmail
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/sendmail
/etc/cron.d/sendmail
/etc/network/if-down.d/sendmail
/etc/network/if-post-down.d/sendmail
/etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/sendmail
/etc/alternatives/sendmail
/etc/init.d/sendmail
/etc/cron.daily/sendmail
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/sendmail
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/sendmail
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/sendmail
/run/sendmail
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I owe you a beer! (I'm a dev, not a sysadmin)...
If you want the rep, use that as an answer (Y)

Comment: Done. Was a developer myself, stayed in touch even when system or db admin became my official task. Some OS knowledge won't hurt you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/sbin is normally not on a user's PATH, only on root's.